# How to get property type of typescript class without hard-coding class or type names?

Tags: typescript

Say I have

```
class Employee extends Base {
    _ename: string
    get ename(): string {
        return this._ename
    }
    set ename(value: string) {
        this._ename = value
    }

    _enumb: number
    get enumb(): number {
        return this._enumb
    }
    set enumb(value: number) {
        this._enumb = value
    }

    _ebro: Brother
    get ebro(): Brother {
        return this._ebro
    }
    set ebro(value: Brother) {
        this._ebro = value
    }

}

class Base {
  propertyTypes(): any {
    return []// array of property names and types, e.g., [['ename', 'string'], ['enumb', 'number'], ['ebro', 'Brother']]
  }
}
```

So say I call `myEmployee.propertyTypes()`.

I know how to loop thru and get the property names. I also can get the current class name which I'm in.
Once I have a property name, I can't seem to get the type name.

There are many subs of base class `Base`, I'm doing this in Base, I can't type (hard-code) the actual class name of which I'm in.

I have resorted to creating a hard-coded map (just an object) inside each subclass which will give you the property type for each property name as a string, but I need to maintain every time I modify property definitions.

Is there a way without doing that? Perhaps with generics?

(distracting example of what I already tried removed b/c it was just causing distraction and not the real point of the question)

Comment: TypeScript's static type system is [erased](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html#erased-types) upon compilation to JavaScript.  If a property doesn't actually exist on an object at runtime then you can't query for it at runtime.  You certainly will never get `"Brother"` from anywhere. If you want such behavior you will have to implement it so it would work in JavaScript, and then TS can help with static typing.  So, how would you do this in JavaScript?

Comment: Ah, I see that you are using a hardcoded map at runtime... if that's the only way to do it in JS, then that's how you have to do it in TS also, as a consequence of type erasure.  Does this fully address your question?  If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: "_the comment says it will [work]_": you must refer to the last comment in the extract of the Release Notes you mention? In that case, it seems there is a big misunderstanding here: that comment describes the _type_ of `lengths` variable, _not_ its actual value. As highlighted by jcalz, types are _not_ runtime values. So what you are trying to achieve either is impossible in TS, or involves metadata reflection.

Comment: @jcalz, the commnent says `// { foo: number, bar: number, baz: number }`. looks like ti would return the property names and the type names. I can't verify that tho b/c i can't get it to run. As to your prev question, how would i do that in js, i think if you have an ES6 class you can get all the property names, and i can even get the property descriptors, but just not the types.

Comment: @ghybs, metadata reflection was easy in c#. can we do "metadata reflection" in TS? that's precisely what I am trying to involve. Yes, let's involve it! ;)

Comment: @jcalz, ok so we can just ignore that attempt of mine and not agonize upon it any more. My real question is how to get the types. what if i annotate all the properties? Can I do that? I'm willing to do that if I can read the annoations at runtime.

Comment: Hmm, you could maybe use [an experimental decorator library that does this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#metadata) but I wouldn't recommend this sort of thing right now; [TS5.0 will probably change how decorators work](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48885) and then maybe after that there'd be a supported metadata library.

Comment: @jcalz, well, I was able to get your "not recommended" solution working. I made an answer out of it. It requires proeprty annotations and helper functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works

```
class Employee extends Base {
    _ename: string
    @emitType
    get ename(): string {
        return this._ename
    }
    set ename(value: string) {
        this._ename = value
    }

    _enumb: number
    @emitType
    get enumb(): number {
        return this._enumb
    }
    set enumb(value: number) {
        this._enumb = value
    }

    _ebro: Brother
    @emitType
    get ebro(): Brother {
        return this._ebro
    }
    set ebro(value: Brother) {
        this._ebro = value
    }

}
```

**base.ts**

```
get graphQlType(): string {
    var typeDesc: string = `type ${this.className} {\n`
    for (var propertyName of this.properties()) {
        let type = Reflect.getMetadata("design:type", this, propertyName);
        if (!type)
            console.log(`property decorator missing on ${this.className}.${propertyName}`)
        else {
            var typeName: string
            switch (type.name) {
                case 'Array':
                    typeName = `[${Reflect.getMetadata("design:itemtype", this, propertyName).name}]`
                    break;
                default:
                    typeName = type.name

            }
        }
        typeDesc += `${' '.repeat(4)}${propertyName}: ${typeName}\n`
    }
    typeDesc += '}'
    return typeDesc
}

properties(): string[] {
    let allPropertyNames = new Set();
    for (let o = this; o && o != Object.prototype; o = Object.getPrototypeOf(o)) {
        for (let name of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(o)) {
            allPropertyNames.add(name);
        }
    }
    return Array
        .from(allPropertyNames)
        .map(s => s.toString())
        .filter(p => !this.ignore.includes(p) && !p.startsWith('_'))
}
```

**language-utils.ts**

```
export function emitType(target: any, key: string) {
    Reflect.getMetadata("design:type", target, key);
}
```